# How can gulp-load-plugins replace all gulp- to g

Tags: gulp, gulp-load-plugins

Default gulp-load-plugins remove all plugin name `gulp-`

But how can make gulp-load-plugins default replace all plugin name which start with `gulp-` to `g`?

For example

```
gulp-sass

other-gulp-plugin
```

rename to

```
gSass

other-gulp-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

From [gulp-load-plugins options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins#options) :

> pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', '@*/gulp{-,.}*'], // the glob(s) to search for
>
> replaceString: /^gulp(-|.)/, // what to remove from the name of the module when adding it to the context
>
> renameFn: function (name) { ... }, // a function to handle the renaming of plugins (the default works)

So you would need something like this (i.e., untested)

```
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
  renameFn: function(name) {

    //  if only it were as easy as the below : the simple case
    //  return name.replace(/^@*gulp(-|.)(.)/, 'g\U$2\E');

   // but try this 
    return name.replace(/^@*gulp(-|.)(.)/, function (match, p1, p2) {
       return "g" + p2.toUpperCase(); })
   // p2 is the second capture group
   }
});
```

The simple case:

1. /@*gulp(-|.) : find the patterns @gulp-, @gulp., gulp- and gulp.
2. (.) : capture the next character
3. g\U$2\E : replace only the 2nd capture group (.) with
4. 'g' followed by capitalized \U 2nd capture group $2 and
5. end capitalizations of 2nd capture group \E [not really needed in your case since you only want one character].

I left the simple case in for instruction but you probably need the longer uncommented version in node/gulp.